# can a stdout captured at a parameter to python script

Tags: linux, python, injection, script

I'm working on a CTF challenge that is find a secret password.This secret password base on the username and password that i input and the hash value had print out after hash calculation and i want to capture this hash value at a parameter to my script to calculate the secret pass
Can someone tell me how can i do it or another solution to solve my problem
Thanks

Comment: Please add more info. Your answer is too generic for people to give meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your python script to read from stdin.

```
import sys
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    param = sys.stdin.read()
    print("param",param)
```

To use it: `echo 'param value' | python3 script.py`

Comment: tks but i want it read from stdout of program because the program will print one value that i need for calculating

Comment: If you're not familiar with linux, the `|` command redirects the output (stdout) of one program to the input (stdin) of another.  So `somecommand | python3 script.py` will do what you've asked.